# Deny access to webpage using passport-middleware for facebook

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport-facebook

I am writing a '**todolist**' web application. In my server side code(node.js) I use **passport** middleware to allow a user to login with facebook. Some of my server side code:

```
var passport = require('passport')
, FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
clientID: '5669xxxxxxxxxx',
clientSecret: '555022xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
callbackURL: 'http://www.localhost:3000/Todolistpage.html'
},
   function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
       User.findOrCreate(..., function(err, user) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          done(null, user);
          });
       }
));

//Authentication
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/Todolistpage.html',
passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/Todolistpage.html',
                                  failureRedirect: '/' }));
```

1) I don't know what the "**User.findOrCreate(..**" part does, which is used in      the passport documentation for facebook  [here](http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook).

2) My homepage is at **localhost:3000/** and the page providing the app is at **localhost:3000/Todolistpage**. I use **express** middleware also and **Todolistpage.html** is a file in my client side folder.

So how do I prevent someone from just plugging in **localhost:3000/Todolistpage.html** and getting access to it when they are not logged in?  Btw logging in from the homepage with Fb works fine and redirects one to **localhost:3000/Todolistpage.html**.

Any answers appreciated.

Comment: For your first question, have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431049/what-is-function-user-findorcreate-doing-and-when-is-it-called-in-passport

Comment: answer #2 can be found in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213707/express-resources-with-authentication-middleware